# NavigationBar javascript won't load in Safari/Opera

Tags: javascript, safari, opera, infragistics

My JS script navigation bar fails to render on an aspx custom navbar in Safari, but it works fine in IE and Firefox. The bar won't expand upon bar clicking in Safari/Opera. The HTML that is generated from the aspx page will operate fine in all browsers, yet I lose my webresources(pictures) in Safari/Opera. Trouble is, I need to get this working on all browsers, and instead of creating a new navigation bar from scratch, I'd like to see if I can tweak and fix this one.

I am using the Infragistics UltraWebListBar.

Any ideas?

DEFAULT.ASPX

```
<%@ page language="C#" autoeventwireup="true" inherits="_Default, App_Web_odbo9ghv" %>

<%@ Register Assembly="Infragistics2.WebUI.UltraWebListbar.v7.1, Version=7.1.20071.40, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7dd5c3163f2cd0cb"
Namespace="Infragistics.WebUI.UltraWebListbar" TagPrefix="iglbar" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head runat="server">
<title>NavBar</title>
<link type="text/css" rel="Stylesheet" href="/_layouts/NavBar/ig_common/20071CLR20/Styles/Office2007Blue/ig_WebTree.css" />
<link href="/_layouts/NavBar/ig_common/20071CLR20/Styles/Office2007Blue/ig_WebListBar.css " rel="Stylesheet"
    type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>
    <iglbar:UltraWebListbar ID="lstNavBar" runat="server" BorderWidth="" BarWidth="100%" CssClass="igwlbExplorerBarMainBlue2k7" ImageDirectory="/_layouts/CGBNavBar/ig_common/20071CLR20/Styles/Office2007Blue/WebListBar/" GroupSpacing="0px" ViewType="ExplorerBar" HeaderClickAction="ExpandOnClick" Width="100%">
        <DefaultItemHoverStyle CssClass="igwlbItemSelectedBlue2k7" Cursor="Default">
        </DefaultItemHoverStyle>
        <DefaultItemSelectedStyle CssClass="igwlbItemSelectedBlue2k7" Cursor="Default">
        </DefaultItemSelectedStyle>
        <DefaultItemStyle CssClass="igwlbItemNormalBlue2k7" Cursor="Hand">
        </DefaultItemStyle>
        <DefaultGroupStyle CssClass="igwlbGroupExplorerBarNormalBlue2k7" Height="100%" Cursor="Hand">
        </DefaultGroupStyle>
        <DefaultGroupHeaderAppearance>
            <CollapsedAppearance ExpansionIndicatorImage="downarrows_white.gif">
                <Images>
                    <ExpansionIndicatorImage Url="downarrows_white.gif" />
                </Images>
                <Style CssClass="igwlbExplorerBarHeaderCollapsedBlue2k7"></Style>
            </CollapsedAppearance>
            <HoverAppearance>
                <Style CssClass="igwlbExplorerBarHeaderHoverBlue2k7"></Style>
            </HoverAppearance>
            <ExpandedAppearance ExpansionIndicatorImage="uparrows_white.gif">
                <Images>
                    <ExpansionIndicatorImage Url="uparrows_white.gif" />
                </Images>
                <Style CssClass="igwlbExplorerBarHeaderExpandedBlue2k7"></Style>
            </ExpandedAppearance>
        </DefaultGroupHeaderAppearance>
    </iglbar:UltraWebListbar>
   </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Without any pages showing your code, it will be harder to understand your issue.

Comment: Well it's all custom controls, and those don't tell me much. The html/css/js that's generated is quite a beast. Not sure if anyone would pick up on the infragistics logic. I'll post the code regardless.

Comment: hmm I was more thinking about the rendered version of the code, aka once it reached the browser. Do you notice things in the console of Opera and Webkit? What are the messages. With Opera, you can use [dragonfly the Web developer tool](http://my.opera.com/dragonfly/blog/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at their supported environments page: [Link to Infragistics supported environments page](http://www.infragistics.com/support/supported-environments.aspx#SupportedEnvironments) and see that only WebSchedule from the Ultra controls which do not use Ajax is supported under Safari, Opera is not listed but situation there is same.